# How to rename database in Heroku?

Tags: database, heroku, error-handling

I've created a new database in Heroku, showing in my dashboard; when I go to settings, it does not allow me to rename, stating 'Internal Server Error'. What can I do to rename my database?

Comment: Have you try 'Alter database' http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-alterdatabase.html

Comment: Where are you trying this? I presume on postgres.heroku.com???

Comment: Standard Heroku dashboard, within the settings of the particular database.

Answer (score 24):

It looks like the method for renaming a Heroku DB has changed since this was last updated; the answer given in [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19982997/903936) is no longer valid.

I've spoken with Heroku support, and the current way to rename a Heroku DB is using the `heroku addons:rename` command (you can look up some brief CLI help on it with the command `heroku help addons:rename`.)

For example: if your DB is named `postgresql-loudly-9983` and is attached to the app `bumping-softly-6892`, and you'd like to rename it to `stats-db`, your command would be the following:

`heroku addons:rename postgresql-loudly-9983 stats-db -a bumping-softly-6892`

Comment: Heroku's naming is extremely confusing to me. It seems like in my app there's a name for a database *addon*, like `postgresql-loudly-1234`, and then when I look at the list of backups, I see the db name `DATABASE`. It's the latter that I want to change. I'm trying to run `heroku pg:copy myapp::DATABASE DATABASE --app myapp-staging` to replace staging's data with production's, and I get the unhelpful message `WARNING... This command will remove all data from DATABASE. Data from DATABASE will then be transferred to DATABASE`.  I want to call those `STAGING_DB` and `PROD_DB` for safety's sake!

Answer (score 15):

It may be clearer to think of it this way:

1. You can rename an **app**
    `heroku apps:rename --app OLDNAME NEWNAME`
2. You can rename an **addon** (in your case, postgres instance):
    `heroku addons:rename OLDNAME NEWNAME` 
   To find the current name, do `heroku addons`.
3. But you also have to understand heroku **aliases**.
   These are how heroku automatically sets config vars for you (its the config vars which the aliases set that you see in your settings page). Here are the [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/add-ons). In a nutshell, you can't actually rename an alias directly, but you can add a second alias pointing to the same place, then remove the old one.
   See [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/add-ons#multiple-aliases-attachments).

Answer (score 1):

Just received this response from a heroku postgres engineer:

*We've recently updated how we handle database names on postgres.heroku.com. In the past, all databases had a "label" you could simply change, and an internal "hidden" Heroku application that your database was attached to.
The change we've deployed removes the label, and un-hides the heroku app name. The name you see on postgres.heroku.com is a full Heroku app that you can interact with via the command line or dashboard.heroku.com.*

*If you'd like to rename it, you can use the dashboard.heroku.com or* `$ heroku app:rename` *from the command line.*

Comment: OP asked how to rename a database (addon), not app

Answer (score 1):

You can use the heroku command line:

`$ heroku apps:rename <old app name> <new app name>`

Comment: This is also a correction to a previous answer that stated 'app' rather than 'apps'

Comment: The question is how to rename the database, not the app.  For the database you use `addons:rename`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it now in the web interface 
go to Apps, click on settings and you will have a rename button.

Comment: This is incorrect, as mentioned by @ryan-walker, OP asked how for how to rename a database (addon), not app.