# How to rename postgres database in heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I've added heroku postgres addon.

The DATABASE_URL is something like postgres://xxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/ddo2ahvosfggq

I want the database name to be like my_app_database. I want to rename ddo2ahvosfggq to my_app_database.

How can I do that?

Can I use ALTER DATABASE? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-alterdatabase.html

There is already a question in StackOverflow [How to rename database in Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18454526/how-to-rename-database-in-heroku)

But the answers is to rename the app. I don't know how renaming app will work?

If my_app is the name of my heroku app. Will the below DATABASE_URL work?

postgres://xxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/my_app

Comment: What is the use case?

Comment: @RAJ Want to have user friendly name for my database

Comment: This is the syntax to rename the database `ALTER DATABASE current_name RENAME TO my_app_database`

Comment: Don't understand what is the motive of the custom db name. Just FYI, you can use constant to refer to your database on heroku i.e. `DATABASE_URL`

Comment: @RAJ - Currently we are doing it using database.yml. Are you saying the we don't need it at all? Do you have a sample database.yml in which the database is configured just using DATABASE_URL constant?

Comment: @SamuelAlexander Heroku don't use your settings mentioned in `database.yml` for production. It automatically generate required things. You can remove production section from your `database.yml` and push to heroku. Still heroku will work fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot @RAJ . This does not answer my question, but it solves my concern. We are using database.yml for development environment as well. So we would like to add "production:
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>" into database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can't.** It's a Database-as-a-Service (DBaaS) and database name is not customizable there. You just get it from the service and use. Since it's not a user-facing detail for web applications, pretty names are of no use. *So why bother?*

Most actions you can do with your database are listed [on Heroku Postgres website](https://postgres.heroku.com/databases). You can:

- **regenerate credentials** (that don't include database name, only username and password)
- **wipe the database** (that doesn't rename the database as well, just drops the tables)
- **create one more database** (but it will be named randomly, just as all the others)

Answer (score 2):

You don't ever really need to type in the name of the production database on Heroku.

Heroku has a post commit hook which writes the production DB details into `/config/database.yml`.

If you ever really need to to query the database without a model you would establish a connection by:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
query = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('SELECT * FROM foo;')
```